# bash function - file names with spaces as arguments

Tags: bash

I have this bash function which takes files as arguments:

```
txz()
{
  file_in=${@:1:$#-1}
  file_out=${@: -1}

  echo "file_in=${file_in}"
  echo "file_out=${file_out}"

  tar -cvf - ${file_in} | xz -e9zf - > "${file_out}"
}
```

The function should be invoked with at least 2 arguments. The last argument is always archive name, the rest of arguments are files to compress. The function works as it should when i invoke it for files without spaces in their names like:

```
txz File1 File2 archive.tar.xz
```

But it fails whith:

```
txz "File 1" "File 2" archive.tar.xz

file_in=File 1 File 2
file_out=archive.tar.xz
tar: File: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: 1: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: File: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: 2: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I also tried creating an array, but it doesn't work either:

```
txz()
{
  file_in=(${@:1:$#-1})
  file_out=${@: -1}

  echo "file_in=${file_in[@]}"
  echo "file_out=${file_out}"

  tar -cvf - "${file_in[@]}" | xz -e9zf - > "${file_out}"
}
```

How should i create the function so it works for all file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use BASH array to store multiple file names:

```
txz() { 
   file_in=( "${@:1:$#-1}" )
   file_out="${@: -1}"
   echo "file_in=${file_in[@]}"
   echo "file_out=${file_out}"

   tar -cvf - "${file_in[@]}" | xz -e9zf - > "${file_out}"
}
```

PS: Note how `$@` must have double quoting in both assignments.